# Adding Datasources to RDLC From External Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc, report-viewer2010

So I have an MVC 4 Application, to which I'm trying to implement Visual Studio Reporting (I'm using VS 2010).  My Business Objects that will be my data are in a separate project referenced by the web project.  Whenever I edit my RDLC to add new Datasets, it doesn't bring up my business objects.

My Function that returns a business object is returning an IEnumerable.
I've also attempted the add an aspx page trick

Still no luck.

I even tried to minimize the situation where I created a blank MVC2 application.  As long as the object I wanted to use as a datasource was within my main project, and I didn't reference any other projects, It would show up in my datasource options.  But as soon as I added another project to my solution, I could no longer see any business objects to add as data source.

How can I get it so that I can use a business object, for second project being reference as a datasource in my RDLC