# How to use an IEnumerable<T> business object as RDLC datasource, the way it REALLY works?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webforms, report, rdlc, business-objects

I have the hardest time creating an WebForms RDLC report with my business objects, in Visual Studio 2010. I am using the designer to build my report.

In the `Report Data` View of VS2010 I select `New/Dataset...` Strange enough, the `Data Source Configuration Wizard` immediately pops up, covering the `Dataset Properties` dialog.

[image: Selecting a new Dataset in the Report Data Tool]

When I cancel the Wizard, I am able to manipulate the `Dataset Properties` dialog somewhat, but none of my business objects does show up. Actually, nothing selectable shows up at all.

**What do I need to have my business object selectable?**

Note: Earlier in the project, this once worked. I must have changed something, but what?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623234/adding-datasources-to-rdlc-from-external-project), but my Dataset is in the same project, on the ASPX-Page's code behind file. I have set it up like so:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyDto> Getxy() {
        return new List<MyDto>(); //TODO later use real data.
    }
```

I have also read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459529/criteria-for-object-datasources-to-display-in-visual-studio-report-new-dataset) but my object already matches what's suggested there. It is a really simple POCO DTO's with no constructor (which makes it automatically have a public parameterless constructor)

Comment: Hi marcel you're probably missing the reference to your business object. try to reference it again and then rebuild your project. at that point the configuration wizard should not show up anymore.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for your comment. But how can this be? My Business Objects /DTO's are defined in a refereced DLL, right, but the method shown in the question is inside the webproject, where I also have the reports (in the APP_DATA folder). How could that not get built correctly?

Comment: @Raphael I now actually de- and re-referenced the model DLL, but it did not help.

Comment: Ok I hope that the problem is this. Check the properties of your file that contains the method if the build action is set to compile. It could be that I tryed it on my sample project and that was the problem. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @Raphael The method was on an aspx page, having the build action on "Content". I now moved the code to another class which has the build action as "Compile" but this did not help. By now I have started to manipulate the Report definiton in XML, to work around the broken designer, but it is tedious.

Comment: I'm sorry I could not help you and I can't understand where the problem could be :(.

Comment: @Raphael, thanks.  That tip let me to my problem.  I was trying to use a brand new class and had never compiled.  Once I compiled, it showed up in the Data Source Configuration Wizard.